# How to run redis on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

My redis server (using bull js) runs fine on localhost when I use it like so:

```
const myQueue = new Queue('myQueue', 'redis://localhost:6379');
```

However, changing local host to the redis url abc-xyz-12345 looked up from `heroku redis` command and then running the app on heroku gives me `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND abc-xyz-12345` in heroku logs. Why might this be?

Comment: Do you use the REDIS_URL system variables (ie process.env.REDIS_URL) injected by Heroku?